# Type error for an unbound variable?

Tags: haskell, state

I have the following section of code:

```
run :: State' s a -> s -> (a, Counts)
run s x = do
        put x
        p <- runState' s
        (1, Counts 0 0 0 0)
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error couldn't match expected type (a, t0) with actual type (s,counts) -> (a,s,counts)
However, p's type shouldn't be constrained by anything should it?

The following is the code describing the State' datatype, in case it is needed

```
newtype State' s a = State' { runState' :: (s, Counts) -> (a, s, Counts) }

instance Functor (State' s) where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative (State' s) where
    pure  = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Monad (State' s) where

    -- return :: a -> State' s a
    return x = State' f
                where f = \(s, count) -> (x,s,count <> oneReturn)

    -- (>>=) :: State' s a -> (a -> State' s b) -> State' s b
    st >>= k = State' (\(s, count) -> let (x,s',count') = runState' st (s, count) in runState' (k x) (s',count' <> oneBind))

instance MonadState (State' s) s where

    -- get :: State' s s
    get = State' (\(s, count) -> (s, s, count <> oneGet))

    -- put :: s -> State' s ()
    put s' = State' (\(s, count) -> ((), s', count <> onePut))
```

Side note, I am also stumped as to how I would get the "count" part of the state' out of the state' so I can write it on the screen

Maybe it's more helpful to explain what run is supposed to do.
For instance if you use a function label, that labels each node in a tree with an incrementing number using a state, and then execute run (label tree) 30
It is supposed to put 30 in the state, run label (so it starts at 30 with labeling) then print the resulting tree on the screen, as well as the "count"portion of the state, which tracks how often monadic operations and get/put are done on it

Comment: Using `do` with a tuple return type seems wrong. AFAIK a tuple is not a monad. So what is the monad you think you are using `do` on?

Comment: The State' monad I thought.
Is it not possible to return something from a do block that is not a monad?

Comment: Even then, returning `(1, …)` doesn't make sense when the return type is `(a, …)` where `a` is unconstrained.

Comment: The statement there is purely for testing purposes, which I should have added probably, the method isn't done yet, and I can't compile it without adding some statement to finish the do block

Comment: @LordofTurtles A `do` block is always executed within a monad. Specifically every line of the do notation is chained with a monadic `>>` or `>>=` to the next one. So yeah a `do` block should always return a monad. This is described in every book on Haskell that you can find. What is the book you are currently studying on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that you're using `do` notation inappropriately. Any block of `do` code must have a monadic type, such as:

```
example :: String -> IO ()
example s = do { ... }
```

The type `IO` is a `Monad`. Your `do` block has type `(a, Counts)`. This is not a monadic type.

I think what you *want* is this:

```
run :: State' s a -> s -> (a, Counts)
run s x = (a, c)
  where (a, _, c) = runState' s x
```

But you wrote something so different from that that I'm not confident I understand where you're going with it. Leave a comment if this doesn't make sense.